# Include dates within 6 months of terminated employees while still displaying active employees SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, filter, ssms

I am trying to include any employees with termination dates ranging back through 6 months prior in my query while also still including active employees as well. I have included the following but it is filtering out the active employees in doing so. How can I achieve this?

```
JOIN Employees1 e
    ON e.ClientID = c.ClientID
JOIN Employees2 d
    ON d.ClientID = e.ClientID
    AND d.EmployeeUID = e.EmployeeUID
    AND TerminationDate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6,current_timestamp)), 0)
```

Also, is there a way to accomplish this back to the exact date 6 months prior to the current date, as opposed to including the entire month 6 months prior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the employees that are active or meet the conditions, then use `OR` in the `FROM` clause:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where e.TerminationDate >= DATEADD(month, -6, current_timestamp) OR
      e.TerminationDate IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than including the logic in `joins` try something like the following :

```
SELECT
    e.*
FROM
   Employees1 e
WHERE
    e.TerminateDate IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    e1.*
FROM
   Employees1 e1
WHERE
    e1.TerminateDate >= DATEADD(m, -6, GetDate())
```

or even better, see answer from Gordon Linoff.

Comment: @BenTen . . . `UNION ALL` is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have to agree with you +1

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks, I agree as well.